# Apache Ignite Persistence and Services

Tags: ignite

Within my Ignite XML IgniteConfiguration, I have services defined that perform multiple functions including reading/writing JMS messages and interacting with the corresponding caches. I now want to add native persistence to the cached data, but once I turn on the persistence within any DataRegionConfiguration, my services no longer startup:

```html
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I'm sure there is a step I'm missing within the configuration. Any help or even better, example configurations is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more context. Do you see exceptions? Anything in the logs? If this is reproducible every time then please share all steps in detail. To be clear: the services do work normally with native persistence, nothing special should be needed.

Comment: Without the peristenceEnabled property set to true, my services will log messages on initialization and be able to send and receive JMS messages. When the only change I make is setting the property to true, the logs go away along with any messaging that was previously working. No exceptions, just doesn't look like the services are started.

Comment: Does the cluster work at all? At least, please share the logs.

Comment: Did you activate the cluster?

Comment: Yes, the cluster works when I don't have the persistence enabled, but when I enable it, the only thing that doesn't work anymore are the services. I can't share the logs (corporate thing). In regards to activating the cluster, this is happening when we run the ignite.bat|sh script.

Comment: When you enable the persistence and activate the cluster first time then all data nodes will be joined to baseline topology. After that by default cluster will be autoactivated only when all these nodes will be started. So I guess that Denis asked you about activation because your cluster could be in an inactive state. You can read about baseline here - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology.